# Is there an event handler on android platform that replaces a physical button press?

Tags: java, android, eventhandler

Is there anything in android which could replace a physical press button with software, so it does the job of pressing the physical phone's button automatically? And could it also turn off after some time?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Perhaps I misunderstood you. An event handler is expected to perform some action as an event was received. What you maybe want is a way to call a button's activation function from any place in your software?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an FX Button, then `button.fire()` will cause the same action as pressing the button.

Comment: sorry i am new, could you be a little specific ,  FX button ? the trigger that would call the button to go off would be time . when i search this on this site https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events i don't see any thing like button.fire()